# React Router: Redirecting URLs with a specific param

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router, client-side

I'm updating a data repository site where datasets are mapped to an id, which is the param used in our url paths. A few datasets got corrupted recently and part of the solution involved changing their ids. Problem is, a lot of users are linked to datasets on our site - some of which are dead now that those aforementioned ids have changed.

For now, I'm just doing a quick client-side redirect on the 5 or so ids that are dead. I just want to redirect the user from `/datasets/oldID` to `/datasets/newID` but I can't find anything in the docs about literally redirecting to a different url. Yep, hardcoding it.

If www.example.com/rootpath/dataset/001 is dead and is now www.example.com/rootpath/dataset/002, how can I redirect the user FROM www.example.com/rootpath/dataset/001 and TO www.example.com/rootpath/dataset/002?

Here's the dataset routes setup

```
const DatasetRoutes = ({ dataset }) => (
  <Switch>
    <Route
      name="dataset"
      exact
      path="/datasets/:datasetId"
      render={() => <DatasetContent dataset={dataset} />}
    />
    <Route
      name="download"
      exact
      path="/datasets/:datasetId/download"
      component={DownloadDataset}
    />
    <Route
      name="publish"
      exact
      path="/datasets/:datasetId/publish"
      component={() => (
        <Publish datasetId={dataset.id} metadata={dataset.metadata} />
      )}
    />
/*    ... 
 more routes etc
*/    ...
  </Switch>
)
```

I'm kind of baffled that I can't figure out how to do something so presumably simple with React Router v4. I've tried several things...is there a straightforward solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the redirect in `DatasetContent` component:

1. Set up a dictionary mapping old ids that require redirecting to new ids.
2. Use the `useParams` hook (or however you are accessing the params) and in the `DatasetContent` component:

   ```
   const map = {
       oldId: "newId"
   };

   let { datatsetId } = useParams();

   if (map.hasOwnProperty(datasetId) {
       return (<Redirect to={`/datasets/${map[datasetId]}`});
   }

   // the rest of your original DatasetContent rendering code.
   ...
   ```

Comment: Very elegant solution for a situation where we unfortunately had to hardcode the redirects (until we get server-side routing set up). Having the `map` library to check against is more scalable because as dataset URLs change, I can just add them in the library. Thanks; great suggestion :-)

Comment: @goldmund You're welcome. And if you have server-side routing, setting up proper 301 redirects would probably be a more desirable solution.